# Check for matching records from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If I have two tables, both containing cities. One table for authors and another for publishers, how can I check which authors and publishers live in the same city? So far I have:

```
SELECT a.fname,a.city,p.city
FROM publisher p
INNER JOIN author a
```

I'm just not sure what would go next to make the comparison.

Comment: Whats the schema of publisher and author?

Answer (score 0):

There's a JOIN CONDITION missing:

```
SELECT a.fname,a.city,p.city
FROM publisher p
INNER JOIN author a
ON a.city = p.city
```

Comment: so if my author a stays in NJ and publisher b stays in NJ should that work that way?

Comment: Good question. I assumed OP asked for pairs of authors/publishers from the same city. He could alternatively be looking for authors from the same city, and publishers from the same city.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without JOIN but using WHERE

```
SELECT a.fname,a.city,p.city
FROM publisher p,author a
WHERE a.city=p.city
```

Also you need to select the publisher name as well

Comment: That's exactly the same thing, but using old fashioned join syntax. Most people prefer the newer join syntax. One reason is that it's much easier to add the outer join step. It's also easier to read and understand the different multiple way joins if the conditions are written together with the tables and not at the end in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT <fields you want to show here>
, CASE WHEN a.city = p.city THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS live_in_the_same_city_flag
FROM publisher p
INNER JOIN author a ON <join condition - a predicate, for instance a.book_id = p.book_id>
```